# If user try to change parameter through url

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

There's a case that the user change the parameters send to servlet through URL,

is there's any way to restrict user not to change paramters,

if not, how can I manage all parameters send to servlets? in a case they are many, is it reasonable to check each one in turn??

Comment: What exactly is the question? Can you provide an example of what you think the user is doing wrong? If you are sending parameters using the query string, then you will not be able to prevent the user from typing in their own values, but you can check them when they come in by going through the `getParameterNames` from the request.

Comment: Every thing in web development needs maaany work !

Comment: that comment didn't actually clarify the situation ;)

Comment: Many work? That's why frameworks exist :) Anyway, **Why** do you want to prevent it? What exactly is the problem you're facing when the user does that? XSS attacks?

Comment: @Bozho, every things needs to be done, we shouldn't ignore any simple thing, @BalusC, when I type any thing in the parameters, white page appears in the browser.

Comment: @Alaa - now that's another thing, you have a specific problem and you need to debug it. Alas, we can't help without seeing any code and without a debugger and your setup.

Comment: @Bozho, I'll try to fix it myself, if I cannot I'll make a post with the problem I face, thanx for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict the user from sending you anything.

It is the server-side where you can add restrictions.

Usually you get only the parameters you need, so additional parameters should not bother you.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid someone from typing in the URL, but what you do in your servlet is filter the input recieved from the URL, with some java code.

**Example:**

Just found an interesting link where a Servlet Filter is used to filter out XSS attacks(As you see, there is no such code that avoids someone to type certain characters in the URL, or similar): [Link](http://greatwebguy.com/programming/java/simple-cross-site-scripting-xss-servlet-filter/)

Comment: That filter is funny, but please note that it's essentially the *wrong* place to prevent XSS attacks. You'd usually like to do that in the view side instead. E.g just using standard JSF or when in old JSP, the JSTL `<c:out>` tag or `fn:escapeXml()` function.

Comment: Well probably not the best example. But i think is close enough to at least prove see what i said in a practical way. That is interacting with the User request by using a servlet or a filter so we can avoid certain undesired values to arrive via the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should check parameters send to your servlet. Thats basically what you do anyways since thats the way clients (such as webpages) communicate with your application.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to hash the parameters with some hidden secret, and pass that back with the URL, then compare the hash to the URL parameters to make sure they match.

Another way is to not use individual parameters, but encrypt them in to a encoded bunch of characters and the whole thing is decrypted on return.

The hash is easier to implement if you don't care that the user sees the actual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you cannot stop the users from changing the parameters.

You must do input validation on all parameter values. If you have a variable that contains sensitive information, you do not put that on the URL. A really bad example: http://mydomain.com/myservlet?isAdmin=1. Information such as that needs to go into a session since that is stored on the server and out of the user's reach.